# how to append values from columns withing the dataframe to one single column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have df

```
A B C D E F 
x y z 1 7 8 
x y z 2 8 9 
x y z 3 1 2 
x y z 5 0 1
```

i want output to be something like this final df:

```
A B C D  
x y z 1  
x y z 2  
x y z 3  
x y z 5 
x y z 7
x y z 8
x y z 1
x y z 0
x y z 8
x y z 9
x y z 2
x y z 1
```

is there a way to loop through and make this automated? i  have 680 columns in total

Comment: `df.melt(['A','B','C'])` or `df.set_index(['A','B','C']).stack()`?